# When does react stop reconciliation and start rendering

Tags: reactjs, render

1. To have browser run with 60fps, react needs to complete its job in about 16ms. There may be cases where React cannot finish reconciliation in that time. Is there a timer that keeps track of it?
2. Also, when I studied about JS engine, it stated that synchronous code goes into call stack and async code initially goes into task queue and later added to call stack by the engine. Then how does React decide when to stop processing and render? Because `setState` works asynchronously, to have an updated screen, JS engine needs to process everything in call stack and task queue. Does React start rendering it when call stack and task queue is empty? Is this possible? Related to question 1, what if it takes too long?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 60fps is likely the goal, but that doesn't mean every React app hits that. React also only has to work when state is updating, other than that it is idle and 60fps should be trivial. Have you invested time looking at the React source code to see how the even queue is handled? Also, just throwing this out there for you that `async` functions are not the same as functions that are asynchronously processed. React state updates are asynchronous, but the code is synchronous.

Comment: I think [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZCuYPiUIONs) covers the topic really well.

Comment: @JanezKuhar That was a great talk, thanks for sharing link.

Comment: @JanezKuhar half way through the video and seems like this video answers my questions. Thanks a lot!